# ValidationError: Product validation failed: age: Path `age` is required., first_name: Path `first_name` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

I am new to Node.js and I know this is a very common question, and lot of people have asked the same question. But you know what none of the solutions are working in my case. 
Please take a look at the code, and let me know if I missed some thing
 Thanks you!!

this is node.js application interacting with Mongo db.
**Product.controllers.js**

```
const Products = require("../models/Product.models");

exports.Product_create = function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body.Name); //For test only - Here I am getting the values
    console.log(req.body.Age);  //For test only - Here I am getting the values
    let newProduct = new Products()
    {
        first_name = req.body.Name,
        age = req.body.Age
    };
    newProduct.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.send('Product Created successfully')
    })
};

exports.test = function(req, res){
    console.log("test controller reached successfully!");
};
```

**Product.models.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var schema = mongoose.Schema;

let ProductSchema = new schema({
    first_name : {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
    age: {type:Number, required: true}
});

//export model
module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

this is the request I am sending.
[image]

I am receiving correct output in `console.log(req.body.Name);` and `console.log(req.body.Age);`. But still it is not saving the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your product initialization

```
const Products = require("../models/Product.models");

exports.Product_create = function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body.Name); //For test only - Here I am getting the values
    console.log(req.body.Age);  //For test only - Here I am getting the values
    let newProduct = new Products(
    {
        first_name:req.body.Name,
        age:req.body.Age
    });
    newProduct.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.send('Product Created successfully')
    })
};

exports.test = function(req, res){
    console.log("test controller reached successfully!");
};
```

you need to provide the `first_name and age` as key value pairs

Comment: Thank you, getting error here let newProduct = new Products()
    {
        first_name:req.body.Name, 
        age:req.body.Age
    }; at age :. it's saying ";" expected.

Comment: thank you :) , told you it might be something simple and silly :)

Comment: Got rid of the error, but still data is not saving in db. empty db is created in Mongo.

Comment: can you try to console.log(err) and check if there are any errors while saving